# Add to cart / Remove from cart without refreshing the page

Tags: php, ajax

I am new at some things and I need help about my store page.
For each item you wanna add to the cart or remove from the cart, the page refreshs and it is really annoying if you wanna buy several items.
I have read that I could use AJAX, I have read a lot of methods and nothing worked for me.
What do I need to do in order to make it work?
These are my add / remove:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{sid}">
    <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="{parent_category}">
    <input type="submit" name="atc" value="Añadir" class="sub-link">
</form> 

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{cid}">
    <input type="hidden" name="parent" value="{parent_category}">
    <input type="submit" name="rfc" value="Remover" class="sub-link">
</form>
```

And this is the function handling the submit:

```
function add_to_cart() {
    global $db, $db_data, $db_acc, $login;

    if (!empty($_POST['atc']) || !empty($_POST['rfc']) 
        && isset($_GET['page']) && isset($_GET['data']) 
        && $_GET['page'] == "store_shop") {

        $data = $_GET['data'];
        $pos  = strpos($data, "-");
        if ($pos == TRUE) {

            $ndt = explode("-", $data);
            $d1  = clean($ndt[0]);
            $d2  = clean($ndt[1]);

            if ($d1 == FALSE) {
                $d1 = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $d1 = 0;
            $d2 = 0;
        }

        $sqli = $db->query("SELECT id, rname, char_db FROM $db_data.realms WHERE id='$d1'");
        $numi = $db->num($sqli);
        $geti = $db->get($sqli);
        $cdb  = $geti['char_db'];

        $sqla = $db->query("SELECT id, username FROM $db_acc.account WHERE username='$login'");
        $geta = $db->get($sqla);
        $acid = $geta['id'];

        if ($numi == 1) {
            $sqlc = $db->query("SELECT guid, account, name FROM $cdb.characters WHERE account='$acid' AND guid='$d2'");
            $numc = $db->num($sqlc);
            $getc = $db->get($sqlc);

            if ($numc == 1) {
                $item   = clean($_POST['item_id']);
                $parent = clean($_POST['parent']);

                if (!empty($_POST['atc'])) {
                    $sqll = $db->query("INSERT INTO $db_data.cart (`realm`, `account`, `character`, `item`, `parent`) VALUES ('$d1', '$acid', '$d2', '$item', '$parent')");
                } else if (!empty($_POST['rfc'])) {
                    $sqll = $db->query("DELETE FROM $db_data.cart WHERE id='$item'");
                }
                header("Location: ?page=store_shop&data={$data}");
            } else {
                header("Location: ?page=store_shop&data={$data}");
            }
        } else {
            header("Location: ?page=store_shop&data={$data}");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I think I am missing some details:
After clicking "add" ("Añadir" in Spanish) o "remove" ("Remover" in Spanish), the page reloads and the item is added to the cart div.
When I try the solutions I have read in stackoverflow or in other website, most of them does not work for my store and the only thing I can get is to prevent the page from reloading but the cart does not update.
Maybe should I use a iframe in the cart div?
I am still reading about ajax but I can not get it by myself.

Comment: 1.On Cart Button(product) click place ajax call. 2. ajax url page : store data, get the count of date & return to ajax. 3. In ajax success : set that count to you cart [header] id.

Comment: Thank you Ash. How could I do that? The best solution I found does not update the cart div.

Comment: you have set carty div id i.e. <div id="cart_display"></div> & jquery : $('#cart_display').html('You Cart Count'); .... Please use unique id for cart div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

Remove the submit button and call the function Add to cart and same for Remove from cart using onclick="addtocart()" in anchor tag

`function addtocart(){ 
get 'sid' and 'parent' value from anchor tag using jquery

$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',

    url: '/cart/add.php',

    data:{  'sid':sid, 'parent':parent  }

success : function(data) {  alert('success'); }
}); 
 }`

Comment: Thanks Chris, I am sure that is a good solution but, for some reason, does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form when generally causes a page load unless the default onsubmit action is overridden and the override function causes a stopPropagation on the event object. AJAX requires JS in which an XMLHttpRequest object is created (or ActiveX for IE) and communicates with server without a refresh by default ( although it can be done programatically). Then your server could return JSON for example or some indicator as to whether the call was successful and erroneous and the client side can handle it accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Patrick. I am new about AJAX and that is the reason I am strugling with it.